# "Error: Could not find or load main class", running on MacOS Catalina

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a multi module application, with the main() function in one of the class files:

```
// off we jolly well go ...... 
public static void main( String args )
{

    // output some data to STDOUT to show what's happening
    System.out.println( "Simulation starting ...." );

    System.out.println( "Running in Enfield with 110 people");

    Simulation sim = new Simulation( 100, "Enfield" );

    System.out.println( "Simulation will execute 1 time only" );

    sim.run( 1 );

    System.out.println(" Simulation completed, dumping results ....");

    sim.dump();
}
```

Every time I try and debug or run I get the same error "Error: Could not find or load main class".  I have deleted and re-entered the Debug info many times, restarted Eclipse, and my Mac, but still cannot run the app.
The entries about similar problems in this site are all over 5 years old, and must have been fixed by now (hopefully).
Any help/advice would be very welcome.

Comment: You `main` arguments are wrong. It must be `String [] args`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but in my app I do have (String [] args), I omitted the [] in my post!  I have also created a simple Hello World app, and get the same results, Eclipse can't find main().